# ClassCastException on thinClient in Apache Ignite

Tags: hashmap, ignite, thin-client

```
    ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");

    try (IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg)) {

        System.out.println(">>> Thin client put-get example started.");

        final String CACHE_NAME = "put-get-example";

        ClientCache<Integer, Object> cache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);

        Person p = new Person();

        //put
        HashMap<Integer, Person> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();
        hm.put(1, p);
        cache.put(1, hm);

        //get
        HashMap<Integer, Person> map = (HashMap<Integer, Person>)cache.get(1);
        Person p2 = map.get(1);

        System.out.format(">>> Loaded [%s] from the cache.\n",p2);

    }
    catch (ClientException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.format("Unexpected failure: %s\n", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I use the thin client of apache-ignite.

I Create a hashmap and put the Person class(org.apache.ignite.examples.model.Person) object into it.

And when I take it out of the hashmap, I get the following exceptions:

```
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.apache.enite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl cannot be cast to
> org.apache.engite.examples.model.Person.
```

An exception is given in the code below.

```
Person p2 = map.get(1);
```

However, there is no exception if I modify the code as follows:

```
BinaryObject bo = (BinaryObject) map.get(1);

Person p2 = bo.deserialize();
```

I don't think that's necessary. Is there another solution?

Comment: Do you really want to put a HashMap as a cache value instead of a plain Person? Consider: Person p = new Person(); cache.put(1, p);

Answer (score 0):

Change client Cache definition

```
ClientCache<Integer, Person> cache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME)
```